# virt-install with mipsel and malta

Tags: libvirt

is it possible to create VM with virt-install for mips arch ?
I tried like:

```
virt-install -n mipsel -r 4096 --vcpus=1 --arch=mipsel --machine=malta --disk pool=default,format=raw,size=10  --boot hd
```

and different other variants of command, but always got:

```
ERROR    XML error: No PCI buses available
```

I have to use - machine=malta  and arch=mipsel
Guys, could you please help with correct format of this command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short answer, it is not possible. MIPS is supported only on kvm level and hasn't yet implemented in the scripts of virt-install. I had to run VM by hands from CLI.